# Laravel Collective Form add value If exists

Tags: forms, laravel, laravelcollective, laravel-form

I have a laravel form on blade page which has a select input. I want to add default value for select only if variable $tour->city_from has been passed to the view. I did it like this:

```
{!!Form::model($tours2, ['action' => 'FormController@store'])!!}

{!! Form::select('сity_from', $cities, (isset($tour->сity_from)) : $tour->сity_from  ) !!}

{!!Form::close()!!}
```

It outputs a mistake: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' ".

Maybe I am using a bad syntaxis? Or my approach is wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just need to change your select to:

```
{!! Form::select('сity_from', $cities, isset($tour->сity_from) ? $tour->сity_from : null ) !!}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Ross! It's helped!

Comment: @SergejFomin Glad I could help! :)